# sinatra routes first path param is a number

Tags: ruby, routes, sinatra

I want to be able to match a route that looks something like

`/2/monkey/session`

I have the following in sinatra but

`/:version_number/:name/session`

And I keep getting the `Sinatra doesn’t know this ditty.` Anyone knows a way to getting this to work so that I can have `params[:version_number]` and `params[:name]` matched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote the code below (Ruby 2.0.0 / Sinatra 1.4.3).

```
require "sinatra"

get "/:version_number/:name/session" do
  params.inspect
end
```

The response seems like correctly.

```
{"splat"=>[], "captures"=>["2", "monkey"], "version_number"=>"2", "name"=>"monkey"}
```

Why don't you check HTTP method or comment out other code?

Comment: Hmm You know what i think it's actually a bug in my middleware. Thanks !